# Huawei E398 LTE stick disconnecting

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, usb, pi-b

I have a problem with the disconnection of the modem after several seconds of connection. Reconnecting is not possible "Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory":

```
--> Connect time 0.6 minutes.
--> pppd: ??[01]??[01]
--> pppd: ??[01]??[01]
--> pppd: ??[01]??[01]
--> Disconnecting at Sat Jul 29 09:45:42 2017
--> The PPP daemon has died: A modem hung up the phone (exit code = 16)
--> man pppd explains pppd error codes in more detail.
--> Try again and look into /var/log/messages and the wvdial and pppd man pages for more information.
--> Auto Reconnect will be attempted in 5 seconds
--> Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory
--> Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory
--> Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory
--> Disconnecting at Sat Jul 29 09:45:42 2017
```

/var/log/messages:

```
raspberrypi pppd[1474]: pppd 2.4.6 started by root, uid 0
raspberrypi pppd[1474]: Using interface ppp0
raspberrypi pppd[1474]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB0
raspberrypi pppd[1474]: CHAP authentication succeeded
raspberrypi pppd[1474]: CHAP authentication succeeded
raspberrypi pppd[1474]: Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
raspberrypi pppd[1474]: local  IP address 10.97.88.33
raspberrypi pppd[1474]: remote IP address 10.64.64.64
raspberrypi pppd[1474]: primary   DNS address 194.204.159.1
raspberrypi pppd[1474]: secondary DNS address 194.204.152.34
raspberrypi pppd[1474]: Modem hangup
raspberrypi kernel: [ 2730.655397] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 7
raspberrypi rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Sat Jul 29 09:46:10 2017 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
raspberrypi kernel: [ 2730.679487] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
raspberrypi kernel: [ 2730.679628] option 1-1.2:1.0: device disconnected
raspberrypi kernel: [ 2730.681488] option1 ttyUSB1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
raspberrypi kernel: [ 2730.681607] option 1-1.2:1.1: device disconnected
raspberrypi pppd[1474]: Connect time 0.6 minutes.
raspberrypi kernel: [ 2730.693755] option1 ttyUSB2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
raspberrypi kernel: [ 2730.693876] option 1-1.2:1.2: device disconnected
raspberrypi kernel: [ 2730.694196] qmi_wwan 1-1.2:1.3 wwan0: unregister 'qmi_wwan' usb-20980000.usb-1.2, WWAN/QMI device
raspberrypi pppd[1474]: Sent 0 bytes, received 0 bytes.
raspberrypi pppd[1474]: Connection terminated.
raspberrypi pppd[1474]: Exit.
```

usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1:1505 file contains:

```
# Huawei E398

DefaultVendor= 0x12d1
DefaultProduct=0x1505

TargetVendor=  0x12d1
TargetProduct= 0x1506

CheckSuccess=20

# Standard profile
;MessageEndpoint= 0x0f

MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
```

Configuration of /etc/wvdial.conf:

```
[Dialer orange]
Stupid Mode = 1
Init3 = ATZ
Init4 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Init5 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet"
Password = internet
Phone = *99#
Idle Seconds = 0
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Compuserve = 0
Baud = 460800
Auto DNS = off
Dial Command = ATDTW
Ask Password = 0
ISDN = 0
Username = internet
Carrier Check = off
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0

[Dialer pin]
Init1 = AT+CPIN=0000

[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 +FCLASS=0
Modem Type = Analog Modem
; Phone = <Target Phone Number>
ISDN = 0
; Password = <Your Password>
; Username = <Your Login Name>
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Baud = 9600
```

Configuration tested on all raspberry models B+, 2 and 3.

It seemed to me that it could be a problem with the power supply so I added to /boot/config.txt

```
max_usb_current=1
safe_mode_gpio=4
```

sudo wvdialconf -  It configures itself which port to use:

```
Editing `/etc/wvdial.conf'.

Scanning your serial ports for a modem.

ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 Z -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0 -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: Modem Identifier: ATI -- Manufacturer: Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
ttyUSB0<*1>: Speed 9600: AT -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: Max speed is 9600; that should be safe.
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0 -- OK
ttyUSB1<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- OK
ttyUSB1<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 Z -- OK
ttyUSB1<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 -- OK
ttyUSB1<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 -- OK
ttyUSB1<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 -- OK
ttyUSB1<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0 -- OK
ttyUSB1<*1>: Modem Identifier: ATI -- Manufacturer: Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
ttyUSB1<*1>: Speed 9600: AT -- OK
ttyUSB1<*1>: Max speed is 9600; that should be safe.
ttyUSB1<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0 -- OK
ttyUSB2<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- failed with 2400 baud, next try: 9600 baud
ttyUSB2<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- failed with 9600 baud, next try: 9600 baud
ttyUSB2<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- and failed too at 115200, giving up.

Found a modem on /dev/ttyUSB0.
Modem configuration written to /etc/wvdial.conf.
ttyUSB0<Info>: Speed 9600; init "ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0"
ttyUSB1<Info>: Speed 9600; init "ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0"
```

I checked and this is not a power problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem, which was wrongly selected device port.

It was:

```
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
```

And should:

```
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB1
```

Raspberry Pi model B it works without any problem without additional power with this modem. We only need to remember to get a 5.1v 2.5A power supply.

Answer (score -1):

Four nodes about /dev/ttyUSB0-3 should be generated after plugging ,try to modify the option of Modem in /etc/wvdial.conf

Comment: wvdialconf - It configures itself which port to use - See above